# Where and how to store files uploaded by a user using rest api?

Tags: azure-storage, undertowjaxrsserver

Currently I’m using a shared storage(azure file storage) to store profile pictures and company logos and also some custom python scripts uploaded by admins. My rest services are running in a docker swarm cluster where all the nodes have access to the shared location. Are there any drawbacks to this kind of design? I’m currently saving the files to the location and creating a url for that file and serving it as a static resource using my nginx reverse proxy/load balancer. So I was curious to know if there are any drawbacks to this design and how can I make it better?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to access, store, and manipulate files in Azure file storage using REST API:

> The Azure File service offers the following four resources: the storage account, shares, directories, and files. Shares provide a way to organize sets of files and also can be mounted as an SMB file share that is hosted in the cloud.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-rest-api)

When it comes to the design, it will depend of what kind of concerns your customers may have, slow connectivity, are they going to need these files permanently etc ...